# Using kate editor for c dev (with the ctags plugin)

Tags: c, ctags, kate

I just started using the kate editor (was using vim) for c dev. I used ctags a lot with vim. So I would like to have the same with the kate editor. I enabled the Ctags plugin in the plugins list. It generates the tags file (.ctagsdb), but it does not load the tags in the "tags tab" when I want to look for the tags I have to manually type in the LookUP field for the tag to show up. It does not populate the tags. I am not even able to use the CTags menu item.

Can someone tell me how to get the CTags working. or if there is a better plugin to do this.
Or is this the way it "normally" works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First of all does the `ctags` database include tags of your project/file?
If not then go to the "Index Targets" tab and add your project's path, then click update index. (also make sure you have `ctags` installed)

Now in the source code find a symbol you want to look up right click on it and go CTags->Lookup (or click on it and `Alt+4`).
You can also go to the Declaration with `Alt+2` or to the Definition with `Alt+3`.
After watching the Definition/Declaration/Whatever you can go back where you were with `Alt+1`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have installed `ctags`

```
sudo apt-get install ctags
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: if/when you do this (for me this was the case when using the ubuntu 13.10 repository) you'll need to change the ctags command to ctags-exuberant, and the --xxx-type= command is changed to --xxx-kind=, the other command line options are the same - maybe other versions of kate are different than mine but so far ive not seen them (4.10.2-0u1) Also, I notice that theres already a program called ctags installed and for me it was that elvis flavor, which seems lacking in options, and you can still do the apt-get install ctags as suggested above to get the better/right one.